# EclipseLink: Inheritance with mongoDB as persistence layer

Tags: mongodb, jpa, jersey, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I'm trying to setup a webapp with Jersey using a MongoDB as persistence layer. My JPA framework is EclipseLink.

I've run into a problem with persisting objects which classes are extending other (abstract) classes.

For example given the following abstract class:

```
@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Id
    @Field(name="_id")
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {

        return this.id;
    }
}
```

And this extending class:

```
@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExtendedClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Basic
    private String name;

    public ExtendedClass() {

    }

    public ExtendedClass(String id, String name) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Here is the `persistence.xml`file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>org.example.webapp.resources.test.AbstractClass</class>
        <class>org.example.webapp.resources.test.ExtendedClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform"/>                         
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value="27017"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value="ip-address"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="database-name"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And a webservice that creates and persists an instance of the `ExtendedClass`:

```
@PUT
@Path("persist/extended-object")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String addObject(@QueryParam("name") final String name) {

    final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    ExtendedClass theObject = new ExtendedClass(id, name);

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist(theObject);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return "Persisted object with name: " + name;
}
```

When calling the webservice with:

`http://localhost:8080/webapp/webapi/test/persist/extended-object?name=test-abstraction`

I can create a new entry in the mongoDb database that  looks like this:
[image: persisted object]

So far so good. However if I try to get a list with all the persisted objects I run into a problem. Here is the example webservice:

```
@GET
@Path("get/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ExtendedClass> getAllExtendedClasses() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    List<ExtendedClass> extendedClassList = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ExtendedClass a", ExtendedClass.class).getResultList();

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return extendedClassList;
}
```

This yields the following exception:

`javax.resource.ResourceException: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField.`

Full stack trace:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-90000] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISException
Internal Exception: javax.resource.ResourceException: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField.
Error Code: 000
Call: Executing MappedInteraction()
    spec => null
    properties => {mongo.operation=FIND, mongo.collection=ABSTRACTCLASS}
    input => [DatabaseRecord(
    $and => [DatabaseRecord(
    EXTENDEDCLASS._id => ABSTRACTCLASS._id), DatabaseRecord(
    ABSTRACTCLASS.DTYPE => ExtendedClass)])]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=ExtendedClass jpql="SELECT a FROM ExtendedClass a")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISException.resourceException(EISException.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISException.resourceException(EISException.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISException.resourceException(EISException.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISAccessor.basicExecuteCall(EISAccessor.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISAccessor.executeCall(EISAccessor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at org.example.webapp.resources.test.ObjectWebServices.getAllExtendedClasses(ObjectWebServices.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1084)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:418)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoDatabaseInteraction.execute(MongoDatabaseInteraction.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISAccessor.basicExecuteCall(EISAccessor.java:163)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:231)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:241)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeIterable(DBObjectCodec.java:292)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:219)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:149)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:65)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.writeValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:136)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:115)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:238)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:154)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:98)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:192)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:264)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:717)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:711)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:471)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoDatabaseInteraction.execute(MongoDatabaseInteraction.java:173)
    ... 71 more
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs. According to the documentation of EclipseLink it should be able to handle inheritance just fine when working with NoSQL databases: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/NoSQL

Searching for the error message also brought up no clear answer what could be wrong with my implementation.

I've tested also a version without inheritance and there the extraction webservice works just fine.

In addition I tested an implementation where `AbstractClass` isn't a abstract class where I got the same error message which indicates to me that it is a general issue with inheritance.

I also tested a variant where the abstract class doesn't have any fields and there the extraction works as expected but the object is not stored as an `ABSTRACTCLASS` but as an `EXTENDEDCLASS` field in mongoDB which seems to indicate a problem with the inheritance part.

From other webapps I know also that using a SQL database with inheritance is not the issue so I assume it has do do something with mongoDB.

So my question would be why does the issue occur and how to get rid of it.

As always any help is appreciated.

[update:] [Frank Caputos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966897/4614532) answer steered me towards a working solution utilizing the `@Inheritance` attribute. This is how my abstract class looks at the moment which seems to be working for my purposes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Id
    @Field(name="_id")
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {

        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `@Inheritace` attribute to get it working. This is how the abstract class looks know which seems to be a workable solution for me:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Id
    @Field(name="_id")
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {

        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I hope this is the correct way of doing it. If not please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

You need discriminators.

```
@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @Id
    @Field(name="_id")
    protected String id;

    public String getId() {

        return this.id;
    }
}

@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@DiscriminatorValue("extended")
public class ExtendedClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Basic
    private String name;

    public ExtendedClass() {

    }

    public ExtendedClass(String id, String name) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return this.name;
    }
}
```

You might also need to set the collection name with dataType in @NoSql.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This didn't worked for me initially but it got me on the a path towards a solution that works using the `@Inheritance` attribute. I appreciate your input.